# Comment a line beginning and ending with a pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad

I would like to comment lines beginning with 'echo' and ending with a quote mark '"' :

```
echo -e "This is my line"
```

should become :

```
#echo -e "This is my line"
```

As I got many lines in my file and as some lines beginning with 'echo' and not ending with a quote mark '"', it's not a simple comment which will solve my problem.

I tried this but it didn't work :

```
    Find : ^[echo]+["]$
    Replace : #
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[echo]` is a character class that means 1 character choosen in the class. That's not what you want.

Use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*echo.+"$`
- Replace with: `#$0`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Your solution works for lines beginning with 'echo' but there are some lines where there is a blank before 'echo', what is the solution for this case ?

Comment: @DjibTgy: Add `\h*` (0 or more horizontal spaces) before `echo`, see my edit.